# Error: While installing the pip install claude --no-binary :all: getting error

Tags: pip, claude

The error log below provided indicates an issue with the installation of the **`claude`** package due to a compilation error while building the **`Cython.Compiler.Parsing`** extension. Specifically, the error is related to the Cython package.

Here's error log:

```
Error Log:

Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp~=3.5->claude)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4.tar.gz (141 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [363 lines of output]
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-3.0.8.tar.gz (2.7 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl
      Building wheels for collected packages: Cython
        Building wheel for Cython (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for Cython (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [341 lines of output]
        Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        ...

        [omitted for brevity]

        creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\Users\vinodnegi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tu2bstaj\cython_18740f5b13e54bed8fab72a9910f685b\Cython\Compiler
        cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\vinodnegi\.virtualenvs\VirtEnv309-_IsHGcK-\include -IC:\Users\vinodnegi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\vinodnegi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" ...

        [omitted for brevity]

        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\cpython
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libc
        copying Cython\Includes\libc\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libc
        copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libc
        copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libc
        copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libc
        ...

        [omitted for brevity]

        copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libcpp
        copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython\Includes\libcpp
        copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\numbers.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\Cython
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Python 3.9 but this package requires Python 3.10+. So upgrade your Python version. Other requirements are:

- nodejs (for developement only)
- Redis (to store dashboard settings so persistence is highly recommended).

See https://github.com/voidpp/claude for more information.

Comment: I have tried on both version of python 3.9 as well as 3.10. Looks like its a problem with C/C++ Compiler. but after adding visual studio with C++ addons and configuring the env variable also, I am getting same error.

Comment: use python 3.10. did you also install the other requirements?